# Margin-top vs display block - Cannot get both working - CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4

The app (RoR) shows a set of rows with posts info. Each row has the *title* aligned to the left and *date* aligned to the right.

I need to have a link working over all the row, not only over the text.

If I don't use *float*, the link works properly over all the row but I cannot establish a *margin-top*. If I use *float*, the *margin-top* works OK, but then the link only works over the text.

I don get what the issue is. Any ideas?

This is my css:

```
.post {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:  900px;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
}

.post a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
 } 

.post a span.title{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 7px;
}    

.post a span.date{
  float: right;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your html structure is like this:

```
<div class="post">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="date">date</span>
        <span class="title">title</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**Note:** I moved the `date` up and `title` down, because we're going to make the first one to float right. You can then use `margin` or `padding` as needed.

```
.post {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 900px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
}
.post a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.post a span.date {
    float: right;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/42vdh6bL/